# How do I make div go under transparent sticky header?

Tags: html, css

How do I make the background image looks like it's under the header?

https://public.brayzenchase.repl.co/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(232, 238, 242, 0.3);
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #37393A;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://public.brayzenchase.repl.co/IMG_0290.JPG');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>Sticky Transparent Header</header>
  <section></section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your example is doing what you are asking for assistance with. Can you clarify a little further?

Comment: The image is already under the header... Do you mean that the image should not be visible when under the header

Answer (score 0):

Appending the background image to `body` will do the trick. You are appending it to `section`, which comes after the `header`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(232, 238, 242, 0.3);
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #37393A;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://public.brayzenchase.repl.co/IMG_0290.JPG');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>Sticky Transparent Header</header>
  <section></section>
</body>

</html>
```